# NodeJS Async - Use it like for-cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

How to use NodeJS Async (https://caolan.github.io/async/) as normal for-cycle?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  doSomething();
}
```

I need serial flow but normal for-cycle not waiting until action is finished.

I am open to ES6 solutions, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) from ES6 which is cleaner and common shared in many standards. And in addition you don't need any dependencies from third party

```
const forLoopiNSeria = async () => {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log(await doSomething(i))
  }
}


function doSomething(index) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setInterval(() => resolve(index), 500)
  }) 
}

forLoopiNSeria()
```

Comment: Working as well. This is maybe better answer, because code is cleaner. Thanks

Comment: Glad I can help you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could always do something like this:

```
function asyncWhile(condition, action, ctx) {
  const whilst = function(data) {
    return condition.call(ctx, data) ?
      Promise.resolve(action.call(ctx, data)).then(whilst) :
      data;
  }
  return whilst();
}

let i = 1
asyncWhile(
() => {
  if (i <= 100) {
    i += 1
    return true
  }
  return false
},
() => {
  console.log(`iteration ${i}`)
},
)
```

Comment: I don't understand can you please add example of usage?

Comment: TypeError: condition.call is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I found another way with usage of `until` function from `async`:

```
var i = 0;
var max = 100;
async.until(() => {
    i++;
    return i === max-1;
}, function (callback) {
    //doMagic()
    callback();
}, function () {
    console.log("Finished");
});
```